# JPA: query not fetching the latest data

Tags: java, jpa

I'm finding that JPA is not fetching the latest data from the database.

My data model has a customer entity that owns a number of order entities.  I'm persisting an order:

```
em.persist(order);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

To view the orders, I call:

```
Collection<Order> orders = customer.getOrderCollection();
```

The orders collection is missing the latest order.  I've checked and the order is persisted to the database.  With the driver logging turned on, I don't see any calls to the database when getOrderCollection() is called.

In Netbeans 6.9, when I stop & redeploy the app, I see the latest order that I persisted appear.  So perhaps there's some sort of caching that may be interfering with getOrderCollection()?  For some reason, JPA is not going to the database.  Why?

How can I force JPA to go to the database when getOrderCollection() is called?

Comment: By the way, what implementation are you using?

Comment: are you updating your table through an external source (not managed by your JPA provider)?

Comment: @Bogdan: no, I'm doing everything via JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>`, in your persistence.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You must maintain bidirectional relationships in your object model.  When you add a new Order for a Customer, you must add the order to the Customer's orders.

i.e.

```
public void addOrder(Order order) {
  this.orders.add(order);
  order.setCustomer(this);
}
```

You could also refresh the object, or disable the cache, but fixing your code would be best.

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

Comment: I did have the equivalent of "order.setCustomer(this);" in my code.  Any idea why I would still be having the problem? But disabling the cache worked so I'll go with that solution for now.

Comment: You also need to do customer.getOrders().add(order)